# How to flag a question asking for a support line for a temporary issue

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638782/youtube-api-uploads-failing-with-error-500) was obviously in need of flagging as it is asking for a YouTube support number due to his arbitrary code receiving a `500` error from their servers upon uploading. The question cross posts a few links to other issues on the net that are similar and shows absolutely no code or specific errors.

I went ahead and flagged it as *a problem that can no longer be reproduced* since a `500` error indicates/suggests a *temporary* problem with their server.

Was this the correct close reason, or would another be more sufficient in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct close reason.

Comment: It seemed more off topic as a support question, myself, so I closed it as such.