# Failed review audit, question has score of 19 but seems... useless?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Recently I failed a review audit on this question:

[Publishing an apk on google play store is stuck at processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134234/publishing-an-apk-on-google-play-store-is-stuck-at-processing)

Now, I have no problem with the audit algorithm picking a high scoring question to be used for audit...  But I have no idea how this question itself got 19 upvotes.  There are no details, no code, just "Trying to upload to google and it's not working, help!"

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: It got a lot of up votes because a lot of people had the same issue.

Comment: It's a "hot network question", so it's getting much more attention than usual.

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically. This question was prompted by a problem on Google's end, so it affected many users, and the question was published as a "hot network question", which drove even more eyeballs to it. Its current score does not reflect the question quality, but since it had only received upvotes and no close-votes it was chosen as a known-good question. Just use your votes if you believe it's not, and the question will end up being removed from the audit pool.

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as in the linked duplicate. Generally poor question got chosen for audit because the problem is shared by a lot of people, compounding by the HNQ effect.

Comment: It's about a "tool commonly used by programmers" so it's just on-topic. Although [it's a temporary issue so it's closed anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254725/how-to-flag-a-question-asking-for-a-support-line-for-a-temporary-issue).

Comment: The bad "this is urgent" thing has been removed from the question.